# How to correctly call default constructor inside another constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

If I call the default constructor inside the other constructor it crashes my program.I believe that `array_` isn't dynamically allocated inside the default constructor.How do I fix this.

```
template < typename T >
class Matrix
{
public :
    size_t n_{1};
    size_t m_{1};
    T* array_{nullptr};
 public  :
    Matrix();
    Matrix(size_t n, size_t m) {
        n_ = n;
        m_ = m;
        array_  = new T[n_ * m_];
        Matrix();
    }
}
template < typename T >
Matrix<T>::Matrix(){
for(int i=0;i < n_ * m_; i++)
    array_[i] = {};
}
```

Comment: Why not use an init function? Constructors aren't meant to be called like this

Comment: Also, how would that default constructor work? _array is null and you'd still be accessing it and crashing every time. So it shouldn't even exist.

Comment: You could delegate the ctor if you have C++11 capabilities.

Comment: @Juke By the way, arrays can be value-initialized: `new T[n_ * m_]();` or `new T[n_ * m_]{};`. No need for loop.

Comment: In my assignment i have to  init the array elements using the default constructor , and the other constructor to create the object.

Comment: `Matrix` is the name of a type, not the name of a function. Although you write the constructor declaration as `Matrix()` , there is no function named Matrix. Constructors don't have names.  `Matrix();` is the same as `int();`, i.e. create a value-initialized temporary object.

Comment: Use a **`std::vector`** as storage. The current design suffers from bugs-in-waiting whenever an instance of your Matrix is copied. You avoid that, plus get simpler code (win-win!), by using `std::vector`. Don't use them raw arrays and raw pointers. Use, like, `std::vector`. Did I mention, `std::vector`?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, this is the only thing your comment didn't mention about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Answer (score 5):

I would structure the code like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
    size_t n_;
    size_t m_;
    T* array_;

public:
    Matrix() : Matrix(1, 1) {}

    Matrix(size_t n, size_t m) : n_(n), m_(m), array_(new T[n_ * m_]()) {}

    ~Matrix() { delete [] array_; }

    // ...
};
```

This achieves the same effect as your code intended (i.e. the default constructor produces a 1 × 1 matrix, and all elements are value-initialized), but it uses core language features to express this succinctly:

- Initializer lists initialize class members, no assignment needed.
- The array-new expression can take an initializer `()` to value-initialize each element; no loop is needed.
- The default constructor delegates to the general constructor.

Be very careful to follow the Rule of Five if you plan to make your matrix class copyable. If all you need is an uncopyable (but movable) type, then change the type of `array_` to `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` and remove the custom destructor.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the presented not-working code,

```
template < typename T >
class Matrix
{
public :
    size_t n_{1};
    size_t m_{1};
    T* array_{nullptr};
 public  :
    Matrix();
    Matrix(size_t n, size_t m) {
        n_ = n;
        m_ = m;
        array_  = new T[n_ * m_];
        Matrix();
    }
}
template < typename T >
Matrix<T>::Matrix(){
for(int i=0;i < n_ * m_; i++)
    array_[i] = {};
}
```

just use a `std::vector` for the storage:

```
template < typename T >
class Matrix
{
private:
    Size n_ = 1;
    Size m_ = 1;
    std::vector<T> array_;

public :
    Matrix(): array_(1) {}

    Matrix( const Size n, const Size m )
        : n_( n ), m_( m ), array_( n*m )
    {}
};
```

This takes care of the default-initialization of the matrix elements.

It also takes care of copying, which would cause Undefined Behavior with the original code.

---

In other news, where you want a default-initialized raw array, or more precisely a “value-initialized” raw array, you do

```
new T[size]()
```

where the `()` asks for initialization.

This is much cleaner than using a loop: it avoids that code, and it avoids doing the work twice for a class item type with default constructor.

But don't do that now: just use a `std::vector` for the storage, as explained above.

Comment: Not sure whether to use `{1}` initialization in the `array_` member declaration, or `(1)` or `{1}` in the default constructor. The choice above (constructor) is pretty arbitrary. Thinking about it specifying in the declaration seems to place related things together, which is good?

Comment: As a point of readability, I would not use the default member initializers here. Since each constructor gives the members different values, there seems to be little benefit in giving a DMI, and it makes it ever so much harder to understand what the default constructor is doing. On the other hand, if you're requiring C++11 anyway, then a delegating constructor would reduce the cognitive burden even further.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a default constructor, as much as you need default constructor parameters.

Delegating c'tors, as added to c++11 were meant to add the option of "doing some base work and then some". In your case, there is no base work, only default size parameters.

The code you presented is incomplete, but if you don't plan on going with std::vector, don't forget to follow the [rule of three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) (now five with c++11).

```
template < typename T >
class Matrix
{
private:
    int n_;
    int m_;
    T* array_{nullptr};
 public  :
    Matrix(int n = 1, int m = 1 ) : n_{n}, m_{m} {
        array_ = new T[m * n];
        for(int i=0;i < n_ * m_; i++)
          array_[i] = 0; // If you want specific values
                         // otherwise no need for the loop.
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: The presence of `Matrix()` will cause the compiler to reject the code due to ambiguity.   Both constructors are an equally good match for a declaration `Matrix<some_type> x`

Comment: **−1** Ungood code, and ungood advice. It would be a good idea to read up on Bjarne's discussion of `init` functions in his appendix about exception safety in the standard library, for the 3rd edition of The C++ Programming Language. Even if that discussion is far from complete.

Comment: I did not down vote, StoryTeller.   I'm still contemplating whether to do so.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, true. It's sort of the result of several incomplete refactoring attempts in a short time-span.

Answer (score 0):

As you've done it you shouldn't, as the default constructor will only allocate a 1 by 1 array.

What you can do, however, is delegate from the default constructor to the one that accepts two values.

```
 Matrix() : Matrix(1,1) {};
 Matrix(size_t m, size_t n) : array(new T [n*m]), n_(n), m_(m)
 {
      for(int i=0;i < n_ * m_; i++)
          array_[i] = {};
 };
```

A statement `Matrix()` in the body of a function (including a constructor) constructs a separate temporary object.   It is not constructor delegation.